Python GIL, multi-threading and atomicity
I have read that lists in python provide atomic operations. I have 2 threads that use a list: one iterates over the list to retrieve regex strings to apply to some objects, and one updates the list at regular intervals by adding and removing elements of it. If I want the list update to be atomic for the first thread, should I use threading.Lock in both threads?

Are you trying to protect a single operation or many? for instance, it doesn't matter if append is atomic if you want to lock a remove and append together.

@tdelaney Many - I'm trying to have the list modifications appear as atomic every eg 10 seconds in a background thread, while other threads are continuously using that list.

Since you want multiple operations to be atomic, you need to lock. The readers and the modifiers all need to use the lock.

based on the description in the comment, what you really need is a readers-writer lock, basically all threads iterating on it can be done in parallel, while modifications to the list can only be done when no thread is iterating, unfortunately python doesn't provide one out of the box

"By adding and removing elements" - if you mean it's doing .append()s and .remove()s or whatnot, then it's absolutely possible that another thread can run between those invocations, and you'd see half-updated contents.
However, doing target_list[:] = new_contents (i.e. replacing the list's entire slice with another) is, to my best knowledge, atomic, and you wouldn't need to bother with a lock. (However, you may still see curious behavior if you're iterating over a list that is being mutated, but you'd see that without threads too...)
EDIT: In CPython, list slice assignment has an internal critical section lock, it seems like.

If you're wondering about the potential performance effect of copying the list before iterating, I wouldn't worry an awful lot:
Given
def iterate_over_copy_of_list(l):
    for x in l.copy():
        assert x

def iterate_over_slice_of_list(l):
    for x in l[:]:
        assert x

def iterate_over_list(l):
    for x in l:
        assert x

on my desktop I get numbers like
                | function calls per second      |
case            | copy     |    slice |   direct |
len(lst)=10     |  3530681 |  3256062 |  4341025 |
len(lst)=100    |   358951 |   357517 |   776750 |
len(lst)=1000   |    65002 |    65101 |    84611 |
len(lst)=5000   |    13293 |    13090 |    16264 | 
len(lst)=10000  |     6450 |     6440 |     8266 | 
len(lst)=100000 |      646 |      646 |      818 |
len(lst)=500000 |      117 |      118 |      165 |


The problem here is on the iteration side. Something iterating, say, item 3 on target_list, advances to 4 but its contents have been rearranged.

@tdelaney Sure. A reading thread can grab its own copy of the list to iterate over if needed.

But that's the point. Iteration isn't atomic so your solution target_list[:] = new_contents doesn't solve the problem. Atomicity of the copy means the list won't be corrupted, but it will spoil an existing iteration.

Having two operations to modify the list would be worse in any case, as the copy-for-iteration could occur between the two.

Iteration is not atomic. Suppose you start iteration and something removes an item you've already consumed. The list shifts down one, but since you are iterating by index, the iterator skips that shifted value.
If you want a snapshot of the list, the thing doing the iteration would normally take a copy of the list:
for i in shared_list[:]:
    do the things

This has the advantage that nothing besides the consumer needs to worry about locking. It's a disadvantage for huge lists, but copying is a normal thing to do and it would have to be a pretty big list to make a difference.
This only works if the modifiers are doing single operations. If the modifier wants to add and/or remove multiple things atomically, then you need to go back to a lock. In that case, all modifiers and any readers who care about atomicity need to use the same lock. Notice that any modifiers would be blocked for the entire time it takes to do the iteration.
There are other operations that work in some circumstances such as
my_list = my_list + [1, 2, 3]

because they copy the list and the thing doing the iteration is either going to get the my_list object before the copy or after. But this is rather fragile. Some list operations would work and others not. It's like you've left a time bomb in your code.

Yes, lists have atomic operations, basically append and extend and remove, etc .... are all atomic, but this doesn't mean your code cannot have race conditions.
For example modifying a list while iterating on it will cause "missed" elements and buggy behavior in either 2 threads or 1 thread.
suggestions to use C style loops for iteration are wrong, if you remove an item or insert into the middle you will "miss" items while iterating resulting in buggy and weird behavior.
Using a lock is one way to protect the list while iterating, another option is to use a queue to submit "addition" and "removal" requests to the thread owning the list, and that thread will be the one doing modifications before it iterates on the list, which is used extensively in event systems.
Another option is to iterate over a copy of the list (copy is atomic) but that might be expensive depending on the list size.
lastly, if the list is rarely updated, and it is a global-like so everyone has the same reference to it, you can do an atomic exchange "swap" where the writer will copy the list then modify the copy then replace the original list reference with the modified one. all workers iterating on the old list will not be affected, only those who haven't started iterating yet will get the new list, this needs a lock if there are more than 1 writer, and even with the lock the readers will not be hindered in any way.
